# Get latest updated records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an "Observation" table in SQL Server 2008. This table has a locationId column for a bunch of geographic locations, a few columns for observation details and a column for latest updated date.

Every week, a new observation record for each location is appended. So a location has many occurrences in the table.

What I want to achieve is to be able to get the most recent observation record for each location.

Can anyone help with any idea?

Answer (score 4):

```
 select * from observation where date=(select max(date) from observation)
```

or

```
select top 1 * from observation order by date desc
```

Comment: It would have to be `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM .....` (note: space and not a dot between `1` and `*`)

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.* from observations a inner join 
(select locationid ,max(updateddate) dates  from observations
group by locationid) b
on a.locationid=b.locationid
and a.updateddate=b.dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Run query

```
select * from Observation 
group by location 
order by viewdate desc
```

Please also give the full details about table and what you want to get.

**EDIT :** Backtick removed.

Comment: All those backticks - around the table name and the column names. That's **MySQL** - not SQL Server.

Comment: This is still not valid SQL Server. When you are grouping by `location`, that column must be the only one allowed in SELECT without aggregating, all other columns must be either aggregated or left out. You seem to have been spoiled by MySQL's indulgence in allowing non-aggregated non-GROUP BY columns in SELECT. Although I think this wouldn't compile even in MySQL, because you can't reference `viewdate` in ORDER BY in this situation.

Comment: If you are really interested in finding a correct (working) solution for SQL Server and you do not have a SQL Server instance handy, consider using [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for simple tests.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your table with a datatype of [timestamp]
execute the following code:

```
select top(10) * from yourtablename order by columanname desc
```

**Note**:columanname should be the column you add with a timestamp type

Answer (score 0):

Use the Getdate function as I used as below.

```
select * from TBL_MP_QC_CustomerWiseCOA_Master  order by getdate() desc
```