# Trying to filter a table in order to get the newest product

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, where-clause

can give me a hand with this?

First of all, this is not homework something like that. I do not know how to solve this.

I tried so many times without success. I really dont know how to solve this.

Take a look at this picture:

https://gyazo.com/a8bde055c05874f031cde53c802aa145

Can please explain me what to do? I've searched, i tried but i dont know how to solve this

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Dude, i've been reading different threads, tutorials, own queries but it i dont know how to do it :(

Comment: I've been dealing with this since Friday :/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can please help me, i really dont know what to do :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228365/1127428

Comment: I assume that you are looking for the newest product in relation to the description right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for the newest item in relation to the description.

The query below gets you a list of descriptions with their new update.

```
SELECT description, MAX(last_update_date)
FROM a
GROUP BY description
```

Then you have to join the table back onto itself to get the other columns back.

```
SELECT a.item_num, a_newest.description, a_newest.last_update_date, a.request_id, a.category
FROM (
    SELECT description, MAX (last_update_date)
    FROM  a
    GROUP BY description
) a_newest
LEFT JOIN a on a_newest.description = a.description
    AND a_newest.last_update_date = a.last_update_date
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!!

Comment: No, im looking for the newest item in relation to itself.. compare to their ítem_number..

Comment: I mean, i have to filter the table comparing the different dates of the ítems.. i mean, i have to do a query that bring me the ítems that have the newest last_update_date

Comment: The new table should contains only 1 ítem with a unique ítem:number.. not a duplicate with the same data but with an inferior last_update_date

Comment: item_number looks like a unique primary key, so this wouldn't make sense, but if that is the case then you can replace the a.description in the code above with item_num

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT
    [ITEM_NUM],
    [DESCRIPTION],
    [LAST_UPDATE_DATE],
    [RESQUEST ID],
    [CATEGORY],
FROM (
    SELECT
        [ITEM_NUM],
        [DESCRIPTION],
        [LAST_UPDATE_DATE],
        [RESQUEST ID],
        [CATEGORY],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                [ITEM_NUM]
            ORDER BY
                [LAST_UPDATE_DATE] DESC
        ) [RN]
    FROM [A]
) [A]
WHERE
    [A].[RN] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!!

Comment: Dude, are you sure this query will bring a new table with no ítem_number duplicates.?